# CSS text limit for each line

Tags: html, css

I have this [HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/erADx/) I'm trying to put two sections as it appears, but if i Have a lot of text exceeds the width and go out of its limit, what can i do? Thank you.

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Email Id</th>
            <th>M/V</th>
            <th>Ports</th>
            <th>Read</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <td>5</td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <section id="top">
            <div id="titles"><b>Inline Results</b>
            </div>
            <section class="left">MV AMBRA DWT 18.536 OPEN: Puerto Quetzal 26 JULY 2013</section>
            <section class="right">quetzal</section>
        </section>
        <section id="bottom">
            <div id="titles"><b>Outline Results</b>
            </div>
            <section class="left">MV AMBRA DWT 18.536 OPEN: Puerto Quetzal 26 JULY 2013 Alternati M/v AMBRA DWT 18.536 MT on 9,4 mtrs Built 2007 â€“ MALTA Flag 3 x 4</section>
            <section></section class="right">Puerto Quetzal</section>
    </td>
    <td>Read</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the important CSS:

```
.left
{
    text-align:justify;
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.right
{
    text-align:justify;
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
#top
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

#bottom
{

    display:table;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
#titles
{
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: could you supply some HTML to go along with this to show how you're using the CSS and where the issue shows up?

Comment: That depends, what do you want it to do?

Comment: Oh... I've included the JsFiddle at the top

Comment: @user1477388 For example, I have the width:50% in section #right and #left, but the text simply exceeds the limit.

Comment: It doesn't seem to exceed the limit on my end; `.left` takes up half the `<td>` and `.right` takes up the other half.

Comment: why don't you try word wrap ?

Comment: @user1477388 yes, but for example in my th the vertical line doesn't match with the text in the sections

Comment: That's because your columns aren't the same size; M/V and PORTS are different sizes.  (Assuming you're talking about the vertical line between M/V and PORTS.)

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about it.

Comment: See how they are now the same size and vertical line matches the text http://jsfiddle.net/erADx/3/

Comment: oh.. god..  I feel like a stupid, I only need to put width:50% in th... ._. Whatever thank you, :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try  `word-wrap: break-word;` in your `css` it will help you to implement or restrict the text as you like

Please check out this [Word-wrap using css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

```
.left
{
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
.right
{
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
#top
{
     word-wrap: break-word;
}

#bottom
{
      word-wrap: break-word;
}
#titles
{
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Hope this will help you